# How do I preserve datatype when using apply row-wise in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running into a weird problem where using the `apply` function row-wise on a dataframe doesn't preserve the datatypes of the values in the dataframe. Is there a way to apply a function row-wise on a dataframe that preserves the original datatypes?

The code below demonstrates this problem. Without the `int(...)` conversion within the `format` function below, there would be an error because the int from the dataframe was converted to a float when passed into `func`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'int_col': [1, 2], 'float_col': [1.23, 4.56]})
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

def func(int_and_float):
    int_val, float_val = int_and_float
    print('int_val type:', type(int_val))
    print('float_val type:', type(float_val))
    return 'int-{:03d}_float-{:5.3f}'.format(int(int_val), float_val)

df['string_col'] = df[['int_col', 'float_col']].apply(func, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Here is the output from running the above code:

```
   float_col  int_col
0       1.23        1
1       4.56        2
float_col    float64
int_col        int64
dtype: object
int_val type: <class 'numpy.float64'>
float_val type: <class 'numpy.float64'>
int_val type: <class 'numpy.float64'>
float_val type: <class 'numpy.float64'>
   float_col  int_col           string_col
0       1.23        1  int-001_float-1.230
1       4.56        2  int-002_float-4.560
```

Notice that even though the `int_col` column of `df` has dtype `int64`, when values from that column get passed into function `func`, they suddenly have dtype `numpy.float64`, and I have to use `int(...)` in the last line of the function to convert back, otherwise that line would give an error.

I can deal with this problem the way I have here if necessary, but I'd really like to understand why I'm seeing this unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your ints are getting **upcasted** into floats. Pandas (and NumPy) will try to make a Series (or ndarray) into a single data type if possible. As far as I know, the exact rules for upcasting are not documented, but you can see how different types will be upcasted by using [`numpy.find_common_type`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.find_common_type.html).

You can trick Pandas and NumPy into keeping the original data types by casting the DataFrame as type "Object" before calling apply, like this:

```
df['string_col'] = df[['int_col', 'float_col']].astype('O').apply(func, axis=1)
```

---

Let's break down what is happening here. First, what happens to df after we do `.astype('O')`?

```
as_object = df[['int_col', 'float_col']].astype('O')
print(as_object.dtypes)
```

Gives:

```
int_col      object
float_col    object
dtype: object
```

Okay so now both columns have the same dtype, which is object. We know from before that `apply()` (or anything else that extracts one row from a DataFrame) will try to convert both columns to the same dtype, but it will see that they are already the same, so there is nothing to do.

However, we are still able to get the original ints and floats because `dtype('O')` behaves as some sort of container type that can hold any python object. Typically it is used when a Series contains types that aren't meant to be mixed (like strings and ints) or any python object that NumPy doesn't understand.

Comment: Excellent idea to cast the data as a string to maintain the appearance of being a int or float.  +1

Comment: Seems like a strange choice to make a series out of a row, but I guess that works well for a lot of applications. The `.astype('O')` thing worked like a charm! Why does casting the DataFrame as type "Object" make it send the original datatypes into `func`? I would have expected to see my print statements say something like `int_val type: <class 'str'>`, but it actually says `int_val type: <class 'int'>`

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is when you do apply(axis=1), your input row gets passed as a pandas series.  And, in pandas, a series has one dtype.  Since your row has both integers and floats, the entire series gets casted to float.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'int_col': [1, 2], 'float_col': [1.23, 4.56]})

def func(int_and_float):
    int_val, float_val = int_and_float
    print('\n')
    print('Prints input series')
    print(int_and_float)
    print('\n')
    return 'int-{:03d}_float-{:5.3f}'.format(int(int_val), float_val)

df['string_col'] = df[['int_col', 'float_col']].apply(func, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Prints input series
int_col      1.00
float_col    1.23
Name: 0, dtype: float64




Prints input series
int_col      2.00
float_col    4.56
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Not super important, but is it "downcasting" to go from int64 to float64 or "upcasting", or just casting, since they have the same size?

Comment: @BenLindsay I am not sure.  I changed it to casted.   I'd have to look at the pandas source code or ask one of the pandas gods on here to be sure.  However, I am certain that this is why your integers are getting converted to float.