# Pandas single row indexing without casting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Indexing a single row of a Pandas DataFrame containing objects (strings) returns a Series which is of type object.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(3), 'b': np.arange(0.5,3),'c': list('def')})

df1
   a    b  c
0  0  0.5  d
1  1  1.5  e
2  2  2.5  f

df1.loc[0]
a      0
b    0.5
c      d
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Indexing a single row of a Pandas DataFrame not containing objects (strings) returns a Series which casts its values. Column `a` is of type `int64`  in the DataFrame. The resulting series contains the value of column `a` as a `float64`.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(3), 'b': np.arange(0.5,3)})

df2
  a    b
0  0  0.5
1  1  1.5
2  2  2.5

df2.loc[0]

a    0.0
b    0.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

This behavior does not seem consistant, does it?
How can I select a single row of the second DataFrame `df2` without casting my ints to floats?

Comment: See related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143631/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around solution, according to the stackoverflow link posted in the comments by @Michael:

```
desired_index = 3

df.astype('O').iloc[desired_index]
```

My dataframe is big and converting the whole DataFrame to object takes a while. Here is a faster but ulgier solution.

```
df.iloc[[desired_index]].astype('O').iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

When there is more than one `type` in the `Series` , pandas will using `object` to handle it , If it is float and int , it will change the int to float

```
df1.loc[0].map(type)
Out[6]: 
a      <class 'numpy.int32'>
b    <class 'numpy.float64'>
c              <class 'str'>
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: The problem is, that df2 has different types, too (int64 and float64). The resulting series casts my int64 to float64.

Comment: @checkThisOut string can not be cover by the change to float , so it will convert to object . type promotion to the object