# Integer format specification 'd' produces ValueError when applied row by row to numpy.int column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, number-formatting

Say I create a pandas dataframe containing both `int` and `float` types:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.3], [2, 2.4]], columns=['a', 'b'])
>>> df
   a    b
0  1  1.3
1  2  2.4
```

It is clear that column `'a'` is composed of `numpy.int64` values:

```
>>> df.a.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> df.a[0]
1
>>> type(df.a[0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

...and I can use the `d` formatting specifier to format these column `'a'` values:

```
>>> "{a:d}".format(a=df.a[0])
'1'
```

However, if I try to apply the same formatting row by row, I get this error that says the values in column `'a'` are floats and not ints:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: "{a:d}{b:f}".format(**s), axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: ("Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apply method treats the values ​​as floating when there are int and float values ​​in the columns / rows.

```
df.apply(lambda x: ( type(x['a']),type(x['b']) ),axis=1)
0    (<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float6...
1    (<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float6...
dtype: object
```

---

To avoid this, you can change the type of the dataframe to object with [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
df.astype(object).apply(lambda s: "{a:d}{b:f}".format(**s.astype(int)), axis=1)
0    11.000000
1    22.000000
dtype: object
```

---

```
df.astype(object).apply(lambda x: ( type(x['a']),type(x['b']) ),axis=1)
0    (<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>)
1    (<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>)
dtype: object
```

Comment: "The apply method treats the values ​​as floating when there are int and float values ​​in the columns / rows." -- Is there information in the documentation somewhere that explains this behavior...?

Comment: really the official documentation does not make it clear, this issue has already been discussed here:  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23230, and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143631/how-do-i-preserve-datatype-when-using-apply-row-wise-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Gotcha. Well this not being clear cost me a number of hours this weekend! The posted question was a greatly simplified excerpt of a larger problem. Glad to finally have it figured out, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let us fix it by

```
df.apply(lambda s: "{a:.0f}{b:f}".format(**s), axis=1)
0    11.300000
1    22.400000
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution to the problem! I'm going to select the other answer as correct, though, since it explains *why*.